# Windows can't find hard drive after installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I installed Ubuntu  16.04 in my D:\ drive using **Unetbootin**. Before installing, I tried to create a partition of my 130GB drive but I couldn't. So I tried installing  it without creating partition. After installing, I could not boot my Windows 8 so I tried Boot-repair which finally let me do dual-booting but now when I boot Windows 8, it's not showing D:\ drive which had my 90GB data.Then, I opened disk management and it shows an unnamed disk with full 130GB free space and not having any format(which was FAT32 before installing Ubuntu). Has my all data been really deleted? If yes, how to recover.
Update: I tried Linux reader and it is also showing that unnamed hard drive but having "File system: Linux Extension" with **only 1.28GB** free space and also **not showing my pervious Windows data**